# How do you scroll an image with on mouse click and dragging with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

You know how if an image is to big, it makes the page super long/wide? And you have to scroll down with your mouse wheel and drag to the right by clicking the little bar at the bottom and dragging. Well, I need to have it where you can click and drag to scroll, as I have a map in a game that I'm creating and that would work a lot better. Here is an example of what I want:

http://scripterlative.com/files/dragscroll.htm?u=1

But the problem with that is that you have to pay for the code and I currently have a budget of $0.

Basically, I have no idea how to do this. I've looked at a bunch of other questions and stuff but none have really answered my question because they're using Jquery, Java or other coding languages, and I need to use Javascript.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't you use jquery  (or another javascript library)?

Comment: I'm not allowed to--This is a project for school and I can only use JS. This function is purely cosmetic and is not required but I really would like to add it if possible. And I know it is possible, I just don't know how, which is why I asked this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download dragscroll.js (https://github.com/asvd/dragscroll), link to dragscroll.js file, and use `class=dragscroll` in a div.

**Example:**

```
<div class=dragscroll>
    Big text goes here...
</div>
```

Comment: Keep in mind you can add two or more classes by just adding a space between them.